# How to store and update a configuration in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Given a configuration consisting of a few values, say displayName and startingDate, that is constant most of the time but shall also be editable by the user via a sub page of a google app, what would be the best way to store and modify this configuration?

At the moment I have something like this:

```
class Configuration(ndb.Model):
    displayName = ndb.StringProperty()
    starting = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

and modify it like this:

```
allConfigurations = Configuration.query().fetch(1)
current = None
try:
    current = allConfigurations[0]
except:
    current = Configuration()
current.displayName = self.request.get('newDisplayName')
current.starting = self.request.get('newStartingDate')
current.put()
```

Basically this retrieves all configurations, limits the result to just one (or creates a new config if the data store is empty), modifies the values and writes it back to the data store. But to me this seems to complicated to be the prefered way.

**Edit:**
In another environment I maybe would have just used an .ini file for this. I'm basically looking for the google app engine equivalent.

Comment: It doesn't retrieve all configurations. Just one.

Comment: From what I understand, query() retrieves all Configurations, fetch(1) limits the result set to 1. But it is still a list.

Comment: why not using a `get()` instead then? what's the point of picking a casual configuration and then, no matter what is the result of that `try - except` block, overwrite the values? what's that `allValues`?

Comment: and by the way, `retrieve the object` then `edit the object` then `save the object` is a correct way of doing things. It's how you did it that's not correct: how do you know you're not changing the wrong configuration? You expect to edit the last one, but I added a new Configuration, so you'll end up editing mine (probably).

Comment: You are mistaken. `query` will return a query object, which is basically like a bookmark into your table. It is only `fetch` that will return the results.

Comment: allValues was a typo from transcription. According to that data store documentation, get() needs a key to work. But I don't have the automatically generated key.

Comment: This app has only one configuration, single user so to speak. So there should only be one config at a time. @Hans Then thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't any other way to achieve what you want, though I'd probably do it more like..

```
current = Configuration.query().get() or Configuration()
current.displayName = self.request.get('newDisplayName')
current.starting = self.request.get('newStartingDate')
current.put()
```

but I couldn't help myself and would have to allow for alternate configs..

```
id = self.request.get('id') or 'default'
config = Configuration.get_by_id(id) or Configuration(id = id)
config.displayName = self.request.get('newDisplayName')
config.starting = self.request.get('newStartingDate')
config.put()
```

Comment: I realize that my way to query the data store wasn't optimal and I will adjust it. Thanks for pointing out, that this is indeed the preferred way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

On GAE the filesystem is read-only, this means that you can't write in a config file and that your way is the right way.

If you want to simplify your code you could use a string ID and get it with the method `get_or _insert()`

```
current = Configuration.get_or_insert('current')
current.displayName = self.request.get('newDisplayName')
current.starting = self.request.get('newStartingDate')
current.put()
```